# cannot make a static reference to the non static type linkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

hi guys i am trying to implement a linkedList but i have an error " cannot make a static reference to the non-static type linkedList. my code is as follows

```
package linkedList;

public class Node<E>{
    private String elem;
    private Node<E> next, previous;

    public class linkedList{
        private Node<E> head;
        private Node<E> temp;
        private Node<E> tail;

        linkedList(){
        head=null;
        temp=null;
        tail=null;

        }

        //add method
        public void addFirst(String elem){

            if(head==null){
                Node<E> first=new Node<E>();
            first.elem=elem;
            head=first;

            }
            else{
            Node<E> oldFirst=head;
            Node first=new Node<E>();
            first.elem=elem;
            first.next=oldFirst;
            head=first;

            }


        }


    }

public static void main(String[]args){

    linkedList two=new linkedList();



}



}
```

guys please help.Thanks

object.

If two request objects id is equal then i need to return true. If two objects ids are not

Comment: the error is when i try to create an instance of two of type linkedList

Comment: You have the linked list class inside the node class?

Comment: Either make the class static - `public static class linkedList{` or move it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Make linkedlist class static. `public class linkedList { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

#### Inner class can be accessed only through the instance of outer class.

Do in this way

```
Node.linkedList two=new Node().new linkedList();
```

`linkedList` is an inner class of `Node` class.